# Testing a partial function in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I have no idea how to write a unit test for testing partial functions. For instance, consider an exercise from Chiusano et al's book;

[image]

where `lazyUnit`, as is defined in the same book,  has the interface below

`def lazyUnit[A] (a: => A): Par[A]`
in which `Par[A]` is meant to be something that encapsulates a parallel computation whose result is of type A.  Because `Par[A]` is not defined and lazyUnit is not defined neither, I find it not easy to design a unit test for testing the `asyncF` function.  I thought about using something dynamic like `isInstanceOf` to check the function signatures, but I suppose that would not do more than just compiling the code.

Any idea?

Comment: This is parallel function, not partial. Partial functions mean something different entirely.

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov I think "partial" refers to "Because Par[A] is not defined and lazyUnit is not defined neither". The common prefix is just an unfortunate coincidence, as is the asker not knowing about `PartialFunction`.

Comment: What do you mean by "`Par[A]` is not defined"? And the `type Par[A] = ExecutorService => Future[A]` on page 105 is what? Of course, it's a bit difficult to test things that are not defined... But in the book, they are defined (eventually). They spend the whole chapter with nothing else but defining `Par`.